# OAuth Flow on BlackBerry - Foursquare

Tags: api, blackberry, oauth, foursquare

We are developing an app on BlackBerry which connect to Foursquare using OAuth. We are having difficulty with the flow. What we have right now is if a user click connect to foursquare, the app will open a browser outside the app to let user do the Allow/Deny thing. The issue is after the user click on Allow, the browser doesn't send the user back to the app. At that time the user is already connected which can be seen on foursquare.com, but since we cannot capture the oauth credentials since the browser doesn't send the user back to the app, we are kind of stuck on that steps. So the question is what can we do to either send back the user to the app where we can get the oauth info or we would also like to embed the allow/deny page inside the app.
I saw some mobile app using myapp:connect for the url callback, our Android dev also using that and it works. But does it also apply to BlackBerry?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first result when I googled for "oauth2 blackberry" happened to be a [post](https://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/browse_thread/thread/da907c5b544dc412?pli=1) in the Foursquare API users forum (now defunct), which may help you.

https://github.com/jeffxchu/foursquare-blackberry-oauth

Comment: Foursquare's developer site links to this library and has additional mobile client resources @ https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client

Comment: thanks, we are using that library. the issue is: after getting the token and fsq redirect us to the redirecturl which is on our server, we cannot redirect back to the app. so we are stuck in that browser. how can we specify the redirecturl so that it bring us back to the app.